# How can I save all page's input values and allow user to view changes when page reloads?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, local-storage

I am building an online bullet journal with numerous inputs on the page. The inputs are not in  element.

I want to save all inputs to local storage. Inputs can be viewed when page is loaded. I don't want a "submit" button unless a "submit" button is the only option.

The code below contain bugs which could crash the program. Please help fix the bugs.

```
//here are my inputs
let eventInputList = [];
let calendarInputList = [];
let checkInputList = [];
let taskInputList = [];
let weekFormDateOne = document.getElementById("week-date-one");
let weekFormDateTwo = document.getElementById("week-date-two");
let textInputList = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

const getArrayElements = (array) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        return array[i];
    };
 };

//here is my variable containing all the input values
let allInputsValues = monthInput.value + 
getArrayElements(eventInputList) + getArrayElements(calendarInputList) 
+ getArrayElements(checkInputList) + getArrayElements(taskInputList) + 
weekFormDateOne.value + weekFormDateTwo.value + 
getArrayElements(textInputList);


//here is my localStorage function
const saveAllEntries = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("allInputs", JSON.stringify(allInputsValues));
};

window.addEventListener("input", saveAllEntries);

const loadAllEntries = () => {
    localStorage.getItem("allInputs");
};

window.addEventListener("load", loadAllEntries);
```

Comment: Please explain your mean of `doesn't work`

Comment: It means there is no error in the code, at least the console doesn't seem to see any, but when I type things in my inputs and refresh the page, what I have typed is gone.

Comment: You're not assigning the result of `localStorage.getItem("allInputs")` in your `loadAllEntries` function to a variable or using it to populate your screen inputs. Once you retrieve data from localStorage, you have to do something with it, such as the reverse of your `let allInputValues = monthInput.value ...` statement.

Comment: The result of a JSON.parse on `localStorage.getItem("allInputs")` will just give you back that string of values you held in `allInputValues`; so, you have to spit it up into the component values and use them to populate the screen inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple observations. I may not be understanding your question and am not trying your insult your intelligence by writing basic info. about local stroage.

1) Using the `input` event on the window element writes all the page's data to `local storage` for every user interaction in any individual element, such as typing or deleting a single letter.  That is not efficient.  The `change` event would likely be a better choice and it would be assigned to each indiviual input element rather than the window and would invoke a function that writes just that elements data to local storage rather than all the data on the page.

You might also want to consider what happens when the user types something and then exits or refreshes the page before the edited element loses focus.  The `change` event might not fire until the input element loses focus and the last change before exit or refresh will be not be written to local storage. You could add additional events for those cases or add a "Save changes" button that saves all the page's data upon click. A submit button isn't required.

2) You don't have to concatenate all the data on the page into one JSON string or even use a JSON string at all.  Right now, you're using only one name-value pair. You can use multiple name-value pairs in local storage, either one for each array variable or even one for each element of each array and one for the length.  For example one name for calendarInputList where the value is the array converted to text; or calendarInputList_1, calendarInputList_2, calendarInputList_3, ... and calendarInputList_len for the length, such that you have many name-value pairs.

In the case of one name for each array item, you'd have to be careful in keeping track of user changes, such as the deletion of calendarInputList_2, because then all values calendarInputList_2 through the highest index name in local storage would need to be updated.  Name calendarInputList_3 would become calendarInputList_2, calendarInputList_4 would become calendarInputList_3, calendarInputList_5 would become calendarInputList_4 and so on, including reducing the value of calendarInputList_len by 1. If you chose that route, you could just delete and overwrite all the elements by stepping through local storage and deleting all names that begin with "calendarInputList_" and then writing the new array elements.

If you want to use one name-value pair, perhaps make allInputsValues an object.  That way the structure will be preserved between stringify and parse.

3) Whatever route you choose, you need a way to get the data from local storage back into your variables and on the page.  If you use JSON.stringify you need to use JSON.parse.  Regardless of whether you choose to use JSON stringify and parse, in all cases, you need to get the data from local storage and write it to a variable and/or write it to the screen.  Your posted code doesn't parse the JSON string, doesn't unscramble the string into it's component parts, and doesn't write those parts to the variables or screen.  Currently, for example, how do you know where within allInputsvalues calendarInputList[3] is positioned?

When the page loads, and if local storage persisted, after allInputsValues is retrieved from local storage you have to break it apart and write each part to the appropriate area on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parse the content of your local storage and set it to the var again ?

```
 const loadAllEntries = () => {
      allInputsValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allInputs"));
 }
```

Comment: Yes I just tried it, still doesn't work :( thanks though !

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an array of id's

```
var ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

ids.map((id) => {
     if(localstorage.get(id) != null){
         document.getElementById(id).value = localstorage.get(id);
     }
});
```

This checks local storage for the values and populates them.  Then you need to add an on change listener to each input.

```
inputChanged(event){
   localstorage.put(event.target.id, event.value)
}
```

This will store the values in local storage every time an input is changed.

Lastly I typed this off the top of my head.  I doubt the code can be copy pasted.  You will need to fix it.

Comment: What are the id'sfor ?